# aggregateByKey method not working in spark rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Below is my sample data:

```
1,Siddhesh,43,32000
1,Siddhesh,12,4300
2,Devil,10,1000
2,Devil,10,3000
2,Devil,11,2000
```

I created pair RDD to perform `combineByKey` and `aggregateByKey` operations. Below is my code:

```
val rd=sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/details.txt").map(line=>line.split(",")).map(p=>((p(0).toString,p(1).toString),(p(3).toLong,p(2).toString.toInt)))
```

Above I paired data of first two columns as key and the remaining columns as value. Now I want only distinct values from the right tuple for 3rd column in dataset which I was able to do with the combineByKey. Below is my code:

```
val reduced = rd.combineByKey(
      (x:(Long,Int))=>{(x._1,Set(x._2))},
      (x:(Long,Set[Int]),y:(Long,Int))=>(x._1+y._1,x._2+y._2),
      (x:(Long,Set[Int]),y:(Long,Set[Int]))=>{(x._1+y._1,x._2++y._2)}
      )  
scala> reduced.foreach(println)
((1,Siddhesh),(36300,Set(43, 12)))
((2,Devil),(6000,Set(10, 11)))
```

Now I map it so that I can get the sum of values of unique distinct keys.

```
scala> val newRdd=reduced.map(p=>(p._1._1,p._1._2,p._2._1,p._2._2.size))

scala> newRdd.foreach(println)
(1,Siddhesh,36300,2)
(2,Devil,6000,2)
```

Here for devil the last value is 2 since I have 10 as 2 values for 'Devil' record in the dataset and since I have had used Set it eliminates the duplicates. So now I tried it with `aggregateByKey`. Below is my code with error:

```
val rd=sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/details.txt").map(line=>line.split(",")).map(p=>((p(0).toString,p(1).toString),(p(3).toString.toInt,p(2).toString.toInt)))
```

I converted the value column from long to int because while initializing it was throwing error on '0'

```
scala> val reducedByAggKey = rd.aggregateByKey((0,0))(
     |        (x:(Int,Set[Int]),y:(Int,Int))=>(x._1+y._1,x._2+y._2),
     |       (x:(Int,Set[Int]),y:(Int,Set[Int]))=>{(x._1+y._1,x._2++y._2)}
     | )
<console>:36: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
 required: Int
              (x:(Int,Set[Int]),y:(Int,Int))=>(x._1+y._1,x._2+y._2),
                                                             ^
<console>:37: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
 required: Int
             (x:(Int,Set[Int]),y:(Int,Set[Int]))=>{(x._1+y._1,x._2++y._2)}
                                                                  ^
```

And as suggested by Leo, below is my code with error:

```
    scala> val reduced = rdd.aggregateByKey((0, Set.empty[Int]))(
     |   (x: (Int, Set[Int]), y: (Int, Int)) => (x._1 + y._1, y._2+x._2),
     |   (x: (Int, Set[Int]), y: (Int, Set[Int])) => (x._1 + y._1, y._2++ x._2)
     | )
<console>:36: error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Float <and>
  (x: Long)Long <and>
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int <and>
  (x: String)String
 cannot be applied to (Set[Int])
         (x: (Int, Set[Int]), y: (Int, Int)) => (x._1 + y._1, y._2+x._2),
                                                                  ^
```

So where am I making mess over here ?? Please correct me

Comment: I am an admirer of Leo C

Comment: Even I admire both of you @thebluephantom for the efforts which you guys put in to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, to get the full count rather than distinct count, use `List` instead of `Set` for the aggregations.  As to the problem with your `aggregateByKey`, it's due to the incorrect type of the `zeroValue` which should be `(0, List.empty[Int])` (would've been `(0, Set.empty[Int])` if you were to stick to using `Set`):

```
val reduced = rdd.aggregateByKey((0, List.empty[Int]))(
  (x: (Int, List[Int]), y: (Int, Int)) => (x._1 + y._1, y._2 :: x._2),
  (x: (Int, List[Int]), y: (Int, List[Int])) => (x._1 + y._1, y._2 ::: x._2)
)

reduced.collect
// res1: Array[((String, String), (Int, List[Int]))] =
//   Array(((2,Devil),(6000,List(11, 10, 10))), ((1,Siddhesh),(36300,List(12, 43))))

val newRdd = reduced.map(p => (p._1._1, p._1._2, p._2._1, p._2._2.size))

newRdd.collect
// res2: Array[(String, String, Int, Int)] =
//   Array((2,Devil,6000,3), (1,Siddhesh,36300,2))
```

Note that the `Set` to `List` change would apply to your `combineByKey` code as well if you want the full count instead of distinct count.

[UPDATE]

For distinct count per your comment, simply stay with `Set` with `zeroValue` set to `(0, Set.empty[Int])`:

```
val reduced = rdd.aggregateByKey((0, Set.empty[Int]))(
  (x: (Int, Set[Int]), y: (Int, Int)) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2),
  (x: (Int, Set[Int]), y: (Int, Set[Int])) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 ++ y._2)
)

reduced.collect
// res3: Array[((String, String), (Int, scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]))] =
//   Array(((2,Devil),(6000,Set(10, 11))), ((1,Siddhesh),(36300,Set(43, 12))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want distinct count . Will your code work for that too ?? As I can see your output, it won't work for distinct values. So how can I do it ?

Comment: Then you would just need to correct the `zeroValue` in your original `aggregateByKey` to `Set.empty[Int]`.  I'll expand my answer to cover the distinct count.

Comment: <console>:36: error: value :: is not a member of Set[Int]
         (x: (Int, Set[Int]), y: (Int, Int)) => (x._1 + y._1, y._2 :: x._2),
                                                                   ^
<console>:37: error: value ::: is not a member of Set[Int]
         (x: (Int, Set[Int]), y: (Int, Set[Int])) => (x._1 + y._1, y._2 ::: x._2)
                                                                        ^

Comment: FYI, I am using spark1.6

Comment: That's because `::` and `:::` are for `List`.  If you want distinct count, using `Set` as what you did is the right approach.  Please see my expanded answer.

Comment: No I have updated my question with error. Please check

Comment: Just change `y._2 + x._2` back to `x._2 + y._2` and it'll be fine. For example: `Set(1) + 2` is fine, but not `2 + Set(1)`.

Comment: Can you just solve my one more doubt? why on the second line (x:(Long,Set[Int]),y:(Long,Int))=>(x._1+y._1,x._2+y._2), we don't mention Set[Int] for y ?

Comment: If you look at the signature of [combineByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@combineByKey[C](createCombiner:V=%3EC,mergeValue:(C,V)=%3EC,mergeCombiners:(C,C)=%3EC):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,C)]), its 2nd parameter expects a `(C, V) => C` where `V` in your case is the value (i.e. `(Long, Int)`) of your PairRDD.

Comment: Okay and in last line we have included Set[Int] for y because we are merging combiners. Right ?